# If $(b_n)_n$ is increasing and tends to $\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{k^2}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{b_n\}_{n}$ be a monotonically increasing sequence of positive real numbers such that
$\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \infty$. Which of the following statements is true about
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{k^2}?
$$

(a) The limit exists for all such sequences, and its value is always $+\infty$.

(b) The limit exists for all such sequences, and its value is always $0$.

(c) The limit exists for all such sequences, and its value is always $1$.

(d) None of the remaining three options is correct.

The question is from TIFR-2023 entrance examination. Given answer is option (b)

I have proceeded by the Stolz–Cesàro theorem. I got the following expression.
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{b_{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.\frac{1}{1-\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}}$

Now if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}\neq 1$ then the answer will be $0$

But how do we proceed when that is $1$?

Kindly help me with how to proceed further or any other approach that can be helpful here.

Comment: Maybe can be useful to write:
$ \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_k}{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_k}{b_n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ where the minor is because $\{b_k\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence of positive numbers and then $\frac{b_k}{b_n} \leq 1$ for all $k \leq n$.

Comment: This is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Let $a_n = \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b_k}{k^2}$.

Since $(b_n)_n$ is monotonically increasing, we know $a_n \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$. This shows that it is bounded.

But the above analysis only uses the fact that $\frac{b_m}{b_n} \leq 1$ for $m<n$. We also know that $b_n \to \infty$, which is much stronger. The fraction $\frac{b_m}{b_n}$ could still be close to $1$ when $m=n-1$, but if $m$ is a constant then $\frac{b_m}{b_n} \to 0$.

Using this, you should be able to complete the proof. I'm including it in the below spoiler for completeness.

> Show that for all $m \in \mathbb{N}, \epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $N' > N$, $a_{N'} \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} + \epsilon$. For this we just need to choose $N$ such that $b_N \geq \frac{m b_m}{\epsilon}$.
>  Finally we need to show that for all $\epsilon' > 0$, there is $m,\epsilon$ such that $\sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} + \epsilon \leq \epsilon'$. For this, choose $\epsilon = \epsilon'/2$ and $m$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k^2} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} - \epsilon'/2$ which is guaranteed since we know that the infinite sum is finite.

Comment: Thank you. Nice approach

Answer (score 1):

Stolz-Cesàro sounds cool, but you can also do it completely elementarily.

Since $b_n$ monotonically tends to $\infty$, for every $\varepsilon$ and for every $n$ there exists a $K_n$ such that $\frac{b_k}{b_n}<\epsilon$ for $k\leq K_n$. Note also that $K_{n_0}$ will work for all $n\geq n_0$. For small $n$, this $K_n$ might be $0$, but by the property of $b_n$, these $K_n$ can be chosen to grow monotonically to infinity. Thus, you may find $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $$\sum_{k=K_n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} <\varepsilon.$$

Putting this together, we see that
$$\frac{1}{b_n}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{b_k}{k^2} \leq \varepsilon \sum^{K_n-1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}+\sum_{k=K_n}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \varepsilon \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}+\sum_{k=K_n}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \varepsilon \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\varepsilon$$
for $n$ large enough. In the first inequality, we used that $\frac{b_k}{b_n}\leq 1$ in the second sum. This shows that the sum converges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you ,Nice approach